# cannot resolve R and project not building

Tags: java, android

I am entering a competition at the minute however within the first day of coding I get the error that you can see in the question as well as my project not being able to build

If you need more screenshots just ask.

[image: If u need more screenshots just ask]

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Rebuild Project in Android Studio